# How am I able to change tkinter widgets variable inside a function without the global keyword?

Tags: python, tkinter, global

```
import tkinter


def why():
    global label_text

    label_text = ("How I am able to access 'label' and 'root' which are global variables, without global keyword?\n"
                  "But can't access 'label_text' without global keyword. WHY?\n")
    label.config(text=label_text)

    root.geometry("900x200")


root = tkinter.Tk()
root.geometry("600x200")

label_text = "Hello Good Viewer "
label = tkinter.Label(text=label_text, font="helvetica 15")
label.pack()

button = tkinter.Button(text="Enter", command=why)
button.pack()

root.mainloop()
```

I understand that we don't need `global` keyword when we just want to read the global variable. But we do need it when we want to change the global variable.

But here I'm changing the tkinter `label` and `root` widgets variable, right?

So, why am I able to change tkinter widgets variable `label` and `root` inside my `why()` function without the `global` keyword?

Comment: Variable without *re-assignment* (that is just getting its content) inside a function does not require the `global` declaration.

Comment: The **_references_** of `label` and `root` are not modified inside `why()` (you can use `id()` to verify), just their options/attributes are changed.

Comment: @acw1668 Thank You VERY VERY VERY VERY VERY VERY VERY VERY VERY VERY MUCH 